# My chdir() function will not work. Why?

Tags: c, linux, bash, strtok, chdir

I am writing a program that asks the user for a linux bash command and then stores them in pointer arrays (kind of like `char *argv[]`). The program must then make a check if this command is a normal bash command or a `cd (change directory)` command. If its a `cd` command then it should use something like `chdir()`. If the command is anything else I wanna use some variation of the `exec()` system call to execute that command.

However I am not succeeding with the first part (`chdir()`).

```
int ii=-1
printf("Enter the command: ");
fgets(command, 100, stdin);
command[strlen(command)-1]=0;
printf("Command = %s\n", command);


if (command[0]=='c' && command[1]=='d' && command[2]==' ')
{
    printf("I am inside CD now.\n");
    cd_dump[0] = strtok(command," ");
    while(sub_string[++ii]=strtok(NULL, " ") != NULL)
    {
        printf("%s\n", sub_string[0]);
    }

    chdir(sub_string[0]);
}
```

Edit:
    I have also tried the following if statement without luck.

```
if (command[0]=='c' && command[1]=='d' && command[2]==' ')
{
    printf("I am inside CD now.\n");
    chdir(command+3);
}
```

Sadly the program isn´t doing what I want it to, and even after hours trying to solve the issue I have no idea why. What have I done wrong? Also if I input `cd /home/` why does the output result in sub_string[0] end up with an extra "Enter key" on the output? Does strtok save the Enter key into the string?

Any help on the subject is very much appreciated.

Comment: are you sure you want `command[3]` inside that if? (The ones before it are 0 and 1)

Comment: fgets works that way. [The fgets() function shall read bytes from stream into the array pointed to by s, until n-1 bytes are read, or ***a <newline> is read and transferred to s***, or an end-of-file condition is encountered.](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/fgets.html)

Comment: What is the initial value of `ii`? Unless it is `-1`, the preincrement means that `sub_string[0]` doesn't contain the directory name.

Comment: I find inputs in c to be one of the most complicated things that I have ever encountered in my education. Is there a way to get rid of the EOL in fgets when you do not know how long the input string is? Or is there perhaps a better system call for that purpose?

Comment: @ Jonathan Leffler: `ii` is `-1`. I will edit the initial post to clarify this.

Answer (score 2):

Calling `chdir()` only affects the current process, not its parent process.

If you `chdir()` and exit immediately, it is pointless - the shell you call it from keeps its old cwd. That's why `cd` is always a shell builtin.

Use

```
char buffer[PATH_MAX];
if (getcwd(buffer, sizeof buffer) >= 0) {
    printf("Old wd: %s\n", buffer);
}
chdir(command+3);
if (getcwd(buffer, sizeof buffer) >= 0) {
    printf("New wd: %s\n", buffer);
}
```

to verify `chdir()` works correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I think I'd do something like this:

```
if (command[0]=='c' && command[1]=='d' && command[2]==' ')
{
    for(i=2, i++, command[i]!=' ');  /* Skip to nonspace */
    chdir(command+i);
}
```

Comment: Isnt `chdir(command+3)` exactly the same thing? I also do not quite understand this loop. when `i=3` in the loop the `chdir()` command would point to `command+3`, what happens after? When does the loop exit?

Comment: That for loop is not correct. It lacks any `;`, if `i++` was supposed to be the test it will be `true` for, probably, many iterations.

Comment: Consider what chdir(command+3) would do if: `command="cd\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20fred"`